# Exclude hidden form fields from submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm hiding/showing a div based on the state of a checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="other" name="os[other]" value="6" onclick="toggle_form_element('os[other]')">
```

Here is my Javascript Function:

```
function toggle_form_element(id) {
    if ((document.getElementsByName(id)[0].checked)) {
        document.getElementById('sometimesHidden').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sometimesHidden').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

This is the "sometimesHidden" div:

```
<div id="sometimesHidden">
    <input type="text" size="20" id="other_os" name="other_os">
</div>
```

Now I would like to use my toggle_form_element function also for excluding all the input fields in the "hidden" div from the $_POST['array'].

But how can I do this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery, or must the solution be "plain" JavaScript?

Comment: @BernhardHofmann jQuery is in use, and it would be great if it would automatically affect all inputs inside "sometimesHidden"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add a [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/disabled) attribute to any fields you don't want to submit.

```
function toggle_form_element(id) {
    if ((document.getElementsByName(id)[0].checked)) {
        document.getElementById('sometimesHidden').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sometimesHidden').removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
}
```

For a jQuery solution:

```
// Disables all input, select & textarea tags within the .sometimesHidden div
if(checked) {
  $("input, select, textarea", $(".sometimesHidden")).attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
else {
  $("input, select, textarea", $(".sometimesHidden")).removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Comment: better to just set the `.disabled` property to `true` or `false`, and it takes less code, too!

Comment: Note that `input type="hidden"` ignores `disabled` attribute

Comment: @Alnitak how can i set this property?

Comment: @Blade0rz in your Example, i have to give my input field the id sometimesHidden, right? Because I think your JS Code only changes the div?

Comment: also, as Tommi says, MDN says this attribute is ignored for hidden fields.  It's unclear whether that also applies to the form-submission behaviour.

Comment: @emjay Correct, you need to change the code to set whatever inputs you need to disabled - I'm not sure what selection criteria you require.

Comment: `disabled` should prevent an `input` from being submitted even if it's `hidden` (in [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) they say that "_...controls that are not rendered because of style sheet settings may still be successful._") but it may be obscure implemented by some browsers. If tests won't clarity this then I suggest to simply remove (rename) the `name` attribute to prevent a field from being submitted.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly set the `.disabled` property on the element:

```
function toggle_form_element(name) {
    var state = document.getElementsByName(name)[0].checked;
    document.getElementById('sometimesHidden').disabled = state;
}
```

It's almost always better to modify the *properties* of an element rather than the *attributes*, and the semantics are clearer for boolean properties, too.

Note that while MDN suggests that this property is ignored on hidden fields:

> **disabled**
>
> This Boolean attribute indicates that the form control is not available for interaction. In particular, the click event will not be dispatched on disabled controls. Also, a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form.
>
> This attribute is ignored if the value of the type attribute is hidden.

testing in Chrome 27 shows that Chrome *does* honour the `disabled` attribute and prevent submission of form values for `hidden` fields.

Furthermore, the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) spec makes no such distinction.  It simply says that "Controls that are `disabled` cannot be successful".